# How to make edmx DbContext inherit from IdentityDbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Im trying to integrate asp.net identity to my existing project
i'm working with Database first, and using edmx to generate the models and context class,

Now in the Context class that is generated with edmx, i need to change the inheritance from DbContext TO IdentityDbContext but when i refresh the edmx all changes gets removed from the Context class,

So my question is how can i inherit from IdentityDbContext when using edmx

Answer (score 0):

**Change these**

```
public ConfigurationContext(DbContextOptions<ConfigurationContext> options):base(options)    
public IdentityDbContext (DbContextOptions<IdentityDbContext> options):base(options)
```

**to this**

```
public ConfigurationContext(DbContextOptions options):base(options) 
public IdentityDbContext (DbContextOptions options):base(options)
```

**Example**

```
public class QueryContext : DbContext
{
  public QueryContext(DbContextOptions options): base(options)
   {
   }
}
```